# PHP - I have a string that looks like an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I get from my database a string that looks like:

```
    $result = "[02,04,05,09,21]";
```

And that works as a string all together, is that possible that I make it an array that would like: array[0] = 02 , array[1] = 04, and so go on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

```
$result = "[02,04,05,09,21]";
$result = substr($result, 1, -1);
$arr = explode(",", $result);
```

Comment: That just worked perfectly ! Thank you very much ! By the way, if you know anyway to do the reverse I would be very thankful.

Comment: Glad to help. The reverse is just `$result = "[" . implode(",", $arr) . "]"`

Comment: Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 0):

Trim the bracket notations from the string and simply explode it with comma

```
$result = "[02,04,05,09,21]";
$result = rtrim(ltrim($result, '['), ']');
$array  = explode(',', $result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```